# Archetype clarification on Umbral Stalker's Dark Descent & Domain

Tags: pathfinder-1e, domains, inquisitor

How does Dark Descent work on the [Umbral Stalker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor/archetypes/inquisitor-archetypes-paizo/umbral-stalker-inquisitor-archetype/) archetype of the [Inquisitor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor/)?  Reading the Domain attribute from the base Inquisitor class states that the Inquisitor gets one domain, however Dark Descent modifies Domain so that the Inquisitor gains the Night subdomain.  Does this "gains" mean that if my domain choice from Domain was Liberation domain or something that I'd have two subdomains:  Liberation & Night, or rather that I would be able to choose the Night subdomain as my one domain?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE. It would help your post to add links to the material you are asking about, helps us reply with all the information quicker.

Comment: Thanks for the friendly correction.  Sorry to have made such a noob mistake.

Comment: I've made a quick edit to incorporate your links into the question itself. I've also deleted your bonus question as we generally only allow one question per post here unless they are extremely closely linked. Feel free to post the deleted question separately, although you'll need to be far more specific about what you mean by 'powerful' when you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straight RAW reading says that you do indeed gain the Night subdomain as a bonus domain through taking the archetype since it does not explicitly say you lose the base Inquisitor's free choice of domain through taking said archetype. So, you'd gain the Night subdomain on top of your choice of any domain among your god's (or ideal's) portfolio.

In my opinion, this also makes sense from a RAI standpoint since you'd presumably be an Umbral Stalker that works in accordance to your god's will. She may not mind that you wish to add the subtlety aspects of Night to your repertoire of skills, but she would also like for you to show your loyalty to her ideals by having you choose a domain that more closely aligns to her values as well (assuming she indeed does not have the Darkness domain already in her portfolio; otherwise I suppose she's cool enough to allow you to choose both Night and another domain in her portfolio if you're truly skilled enough to be an Umbral Stalker).

Comment: ok thanks, I was planning on doing Desna and doing a 'take back the night' kind of thing.  There was confusion as to whether you gain it as a bonus or gain it as an option since this modification is a straight upgrade on the base Inquisitor's Domain attribute.  I guess that is what it is though?

Comment: Perhaps it was an designer oversight, but that's how it indeed reads.